# Loop through entries in PostgreSQL to make sure a column is unique

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
create table "deneme" (
    id serial primary key,
    uuid integer not null
    on_air boolean default false
)
```

**THE GOAL:** `uuid` column is a type of six-digit number. There can't be any duplicate `uuid` s among the entries where `on_air` is true.

I want to have a function that achieves this. In other words, while I insert a new entry to this table, I want Postgres to generate a six-digit `uuid` until it's unique among the entries where `on_air` is true.

**MY APPROACH:** So I've tried to follow a logic like this:

```
do $$
declare
    uuid integer := cast(000000 + floor(random() * 999999) as int);
begin
    while (select exists(select 1 from deneme where uuid = uuid and on_air = true)) loop
        uuid integer := cast(000000 + floor(random() * 999999) as int)
    end loop;
    insert into deneme (uuid, on_air) values (uuid, true);
    end;
end $$;
```

I basically loop through the entries where the entry is `on_air` and I try to change `uuid` until it's unique. But of course, it throws an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "uuid"
```

So I thought that this approach might not be the best. **How can I achieve the goal?**

Comment: And why don't you use a unique key on uuid + on_air ?? The DB will do the job for you

Comment: I want to keep `uuid` column in six-digits. That's why I'm using this: `cast(000000 + floor(random() * 999999) as int)`. And also it should only check the entries where `on_air = true` and disregard when `on_air = false`.

Comment: You can create a partial unique index with the condition `where on_air = true`

Comment: How to do that @a_horse_with_no_name ?

I have a different idea based on what @nacho suggested: I'll leave `uuid` nullable and just change `uuid` to null when `on_air` is false: 

`create table "deneme" (id serial primary key, uuid integer, on_air boolean default false, unique(uuid, on_air));`

Would this achieve the goal?

Comment: `create unique index on deneme (uuid) where on_air = false;`

Comment: How can I make it generate random `uuid` s until it's unique then?

Comment: No, that won't do it. If uuid is nullable, it can't be unique. You need to use @a_horse_with_no_name solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I changed `uuid` column to be nullable and added a `unique(uuid, on_air)` in the table.

And created this function:

```
    do $$
    declare
        new_uuid integer =  CAST(000000 + floor(random() * 999999) AS int);
    begin
        while (select exists(select 1 from deneme where uuid = new_uuid and on_air = true)) loop
            new_uuid := cast(000000 + floor(random() * 999999) as int);
        end loop;
    insert into deneme (uuid, on_air) values (new_uuid, true);
    end $$;
```

So it will keep on creating a new uuid until it's unique.